# Oracle Client for Console screen

Tags: linux, oracle

I want to install an Oracle Client like SQLDeveloper differing in that it works on Linux shell console, there will not be GUI.

Do you to recommend most usefull one?

Comment: What's wrong with Oracle's `SQL*Plus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL*Plus is basically the SQLDeveloper without the GUI.

> SQL*Plus is the most basic Oracle Database utility, with a basic command-line interface, commonly used by users, administrators, and programmers.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL%2aPlus)
Check also [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aPlus_FAQ) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/toc.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

- pure SqlPlus
- something called yasql (written in Perl), this one uses libreadline so you can use TAB comletiton, and also it can redirect sql output into CSV and other formats
- SqlPlus executed from Emacs (`sql-oracle` mode). This also adds some additional features.

Oracle does not have any nice tool like Informix'es dbaccess.